# Misleading hyperlink when flagging in app

Tags: bug, android-app

When flagging a comment in the Android app, the "rude" option contains text that is formatted as a hyperlink, but pressing it simply selects that option and closes the dialog.

Either allow users to follow that link, or don't format that text as a hyperlink.

[image: screenshot demonstrating the hyperlink formatting]